# how to access google contacts using oauth in java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-shared-contacts

Previously i can access google contacts using consumer key and consumer secret.

```
GoogleOAuthParameters  objParametersPro = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
ContactsService contactService = new ContactsService("App_Name");
objParametersPro.setOAuthConsumerKey(m_sConsumerKey);
objParametersPro.setOAuthConsumerSecret(m_sConsumerSecret);
objParametersPro.setOAuthType(OAuthType.TWO_LEGGED_OAUTH);
OAuthSigner objSignerPrp = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
objParametersPro.addCustomBaseParameter("xoauth_requestor_id",adminEmail);
contactService.setOAuthCredentials(objParametersPro, objSignerPrp);
contactService.setHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");
try {
    String url="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/"+domain+"/full/"+contactId;
                entry = contactService.getEntry(new URL(url),ContactEntry.class);
} catch (Exception e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
log.warning("exception in create entry obj"+e1);
}
```

But now i am have to use oauth 2.0. can anyone have sample example of it or piece of code ?

Comment: I am getting below error com.google.gdata.util.ResourceNotFoundException: OK
<html><head>
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
<p><b>404.</b>
<ins>That&#39;s an error.</ins></p>
<p>The requested URL <code>/m8</code> was not found on this server.
<ins>That&#39;s all we know.</ins></p></body></html> . i have already added contact url into scope. what thing am i missing..?

Comment: can anyone tell me what am i missing ..?